# Capturing address info during order process in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models, relationships

I am building an ecommerce app in rails and would like some help on my model relationships and how i get the tables populated with the information.

I have a user model, an order model and an address model. I want to capture the address in a form during the order process. 
In my order model i have user_id, pay_type, email, address_id and name. 
In my address I have the user_id, (then some address fields).

the relationships are

```
order belongs_to a user

address belongs_to a user

address belongs_to an order

order has_one address

user has_many orders

user has_one address
```

So when a customer clicks checkout I want them to enter the name thats on the Order, email, address and paytype. The user_id will be captured using currently signed in user method through a hidden field. (If there is a better way let me know). sorry if this isn't explained very well

Comment: Please show the code you have so far. Also, setting the `user_id` through a hidden form field is a **very bad** idea. It is completely insecure and allows anyone to spoof the user id. Instead use a session to store the user_id of the logged in user.

Comment: which part of the code do you wish to see? The form for orders or address? my controllers? my models?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to look into accepts_nested_attributes and nesting forms.

Or just look through some code [here](https://github.com/stephskardal/piggybak), e.g.

- [order model](https://github.com/stephskardal/piggybak/blob/master/app/models/piggybak/order.rb)
- [order form](https://github.com/stephskardal/piggybak/blob/master/app/views/piggybak/orders/submit.html.erb)
- [order controller](https://github.com/stephskardal/piggybak/blob/master/app/controllers/piggybak/orders_controller.rb)

The main things here to note are:

- accepts_nested_attributes_for
- f.fields_for :address do |address| will be needed to render the nested form
- @order.save in the controller will save all nested data